# Upgrade or not upgrade to Ionic 3?

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

So, finally Ionic 3.x was released and I'm thinking... all the new updates and improvements will be applied in the version 3?

My question goes because we are starting a project in Ionic 2 a few weeks ago and we don't know if we must upgrade to version 3 or continuing with the version 2.

What do you recommend? continuing with Ionic 2 and maybe later upgrade to version 3, or start immediately with the version 3 (because the project is starting).

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Not the best question for SO :) I would remove it so you don't get downvoted. Look through the documentation and see if the changes are worthy of upgrading

Comment: Ionic uses Semantic Versioning http://semver.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty obvious. You are starting off with your project. Ionic has released 3.0 . So you should start with `Ionic 3`. Ionic used semantic versioning, so there are breaking changes. This comes mostly from changes in `Angular` which moved from `2` to `4` . ( Why not `3` ? Because of some conflicts in semantic versioning of dependent modules, `Router` module if I remember correctly ).

It brings a lot of improvements, mainly reduction in bundle size which is going to help in loading time. And there are more, like `ionic-native 3`. Check out [ChangeLog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) . So I dont see a reason why you shouldnt.

Comment: I agree. I upgraded my app that has been much longer in development and we had no issues. The only thing that I recall was that storage had to be declared in constructor (private storage: Storage instead of storage: Storage = new Storage())